# Insert empty row in database

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

An idea 
why this code insert an empty row into database sqlite3

I am new to python programming and also in tkinter.

```
def Database():  #Database Connection
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("carrent.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

def Add_New_Car():
    screen2 =Toplevel(Home)
    screen2.configure(background='turquoise')
    screen2.title("Add New Car")
    screen2.geometry("500x450")
    name = StringVar()
    Reg_number=StringVar()
    Model = StringVar()
    Meter_Reading = StringVar()
    Status = StringVar()
    Label(screen2, text="Name", width=45).pack()
    Entry(screen2,textvariable = name).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Registration Number *",width=45,).pack()
    Entry(screen2,textvariable = Reg_number).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Model", width=45).pack()
    Entry(screen2,textvariable = Model).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Meter Reading",width=45,).pack()
    Entry(screen2,textvariable = Meter_Reading).pack()
    Label(screen2, text="Status", width=45).pack()
    Entry(screen2,textvariable = Status).pack()
    b1=Button(screen2, text="Add", width=45, 
    bg="blue",command=Add_Car_Data)
    b1.pack()

    def Add_Car_Data():
        Database()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `cars` VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?)", 
        (str(name.get()) ,str(Reg_number.get()),str(Model.get()),
        str(Meter_Reading.get()),str(Status.get())))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

INSERT INTO cars DEFAULT VALUES